# Replace values from pandas dataset with dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, replace

I am extracting a column from **excel** document with **pandas**. After that, I want to replace for each row of the selected column, all keys contained in multiple dictionaries grouped in a list.

```
import pandas as pd
file_loc = "excelFile.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(file_loc, usecols = "C")
```

In this case, my **dataframe** is called by df['Q10'], this data frame has more than 10k rows.

Traditionally, if I want to replace a value in df I use;

```
df['Q10'].str.replace('val1', 'val1')
```

Now, I have a dictionary of words like:

```
mydic = [
   {
      'key': 'wasn't',
      'value': 'was not' 
   }
   {
      'key': 'I'm',
      'value': 'I am' 
   }
   ... + tons of line of key value pairs
]
```

Currently, I have created a function that iterates over "mydic" and replacer one by one all occurrences.

```
def replaceContractions(df, mydic):
    for cont in contractions:
        df.str.replace(cont['key'], cont['value'])
```

Next I call this function passing mydic and my dataframe:

```
replaceContractions(df['Q10'], contractions)
```

First problem: this is very expensive because mydic has a lot of item and data set is iterate for each item on it.

Second: It seems that doesn't works :(

Any Ideas?

Comment: Your "dictionary of words" isn't a dictionary, it is a list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes sorry It was a mistake, I corrected the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your "dictionary" to a more friendly format:

```
m = {d['key'] : d['value'] for d in mydic}
```

```
m   
{"I'm": 'I am', "wasn't": 'was not'}
```

Next, call `replace` with the `regex` switch and pass `m` to it.

```
df['Q10'] = df['Q10'].replace(m, regex=True)
```

`replace` accepts a dictionary of key-replacement pairs, and it should be much faster than iterating over each key-replacement at a time.